Issue with Excited State Calculations in VASP Using FERDO and FERWE
I am currently trying to perform a constrained calculation in VASP where I excite an electron from one state to another. To achieve this, I am using the FERDO and FERWE tags as per the guidelines. However, despite not encountering any errors during the calculation, I am observing that the electron configuration remains the same as in the ground state.
